# cambiar delimitador doble comillas php

Tags: php, fopen, fgetcsv

Tengo este codigo que lee un csv luego lo sube a Mysql bien, el Csv viene delimitado por doble comillas y un tap quedando algo asi "**NUL**" pero en realidad se ve en texto asi: **"  "**, parece un espacio en blanco entre las dos dobles comillas pero en realidad es un **TAB**

```
    //leo el archivo que contiene los datos del producto
    $data = fopen ("http://localhost/products.csv" , "r" );
    //Leo linea por linea del archivo hasta un maximo de 1000 caracteres por linea leida 
    while (($datos =fgetcsv($web,1000,';')) !== FALSE )
     {
 $linea[]=array(
 'modelo'=>$datos[0],
 );
}
```

en el delimitador `fgetcsv($web,1000,';')` he cambiado el ; por esto:

```
    fgetcsv($web,1000,'" ")
    fgetcsv($web,1000,'/" ")
    fgetcsv($web,1000,'"\t")
    fgetcsv($web,1000,'\" ")
    fgetcsv($web,1000,'~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~'))
```

y ninguno me ha funcionado no puedo volcar ya que me da error el php queda en blanco y la tabla queda vacía no se como cambiar el limitador para que lea cuando es doble comilla "  ".

Comment: Prueba con `”\t”`

Comment: tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar el tab como delimitador debes utilizar `"\t"` tal como lo indica la [documentación de fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

En tu caso no te funcionó debido a que tienes `fgetcsv($web,1000,'"\t")`, las comillas mal puestas.

Entonces deberías utilizar: `fgetcsv($web,1000,"\t")`.

**Ejemplo citado de la documentación**

```
<?php
function parse($file) {
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) === FALSE) return;
    while (($cols = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        foreach( $cols as $key => $val ) {
            $cols[$key] = trim( $cols[$key] );
            $cols[$key] = iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', $cols[$key]."\0") ;
            $cols[$key] = str_replace('""', '"', $cols[$key]);
            $cols[$key] = preg_replace("/^\"(.*)\"$/sim", "$1", $cols[$key]);
        }
        echo print_r($cols, 1);
    }
}
?>
```

> Si no te funciona la separación, primero asegúrate de estar utilizando el delimitador correspondiente, del contrario, el fichero de entrada podría ser el problema y no el código. Recuerda que el delimitador solo puede ser 1 carácter.