# cambiar tab a punto y coma dentro de csv archivo en php

Tags: php, fopen, fgetcsv

hola tengo un archivo http://localhost/products.csv que tiene mas de 1000 líneas y esta delimitado por **tab** y **dobles comillas** y finaliza la linea con un **LF** se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que se pueda transformar antes de subirlo a mysql a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito subir esto a un mysql el codigo para subirlo ya lo tengo hecho es este:

he logrado convertir las " en ; ahora tengo otro problema, que no se como delimitar la linea para que pase a la siguiente linea, ya que todo termina en ;

***como finalizo la linea????***

estoy utilizando esto para subir el csv a MYSQL Funciona si el CSV viene con ; ya cambie el **fgetcsv($tabla,1000,";")** por **fgetcsv($tabla,1000,"\n")** por **fgetcsv($tabla,1000,"\t")** y no funciona

```
<?php
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "base_datos");
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
        // Leer todo el archivo, eliminando comillas
    $tabla = str_replace('"', '', file_get_contents("http://localhost/products.csv"));
    // Separar por líneas
    $lineas = explode("\n", $tabla);
    // Recorrer cada línea
    foreach($lineas as $tmp)
    {
        // Eliminar posibles espacios y retorno de carro; separar por tabulador
        $datos = explode("\t", trim($tmp));
        $linea[]=array(
            'modelo'=>$datos[0],
            'nombre'=>utf8_decode(utf8_encode($datos[1])),
            'descripcion'=>utf8_decode(utf8_encode($datos[2])),
        ); //Arreglo Bidimensional para guardar los datos de cada linea leída del archivo
    }

    foreach($linea as $indice=>$value) //Iteracion el array para extraer cada uno de los valores almacenados en cada items
    {
    $modelo=$value["modelo"];
    $nombre=$value["nombre"];
    $descripcion=$value["descripcion"];

    if ($insert=mysqli_query($con,"insert into tabla (nombre, descripcion, modelo) values('$nombre','$descripcion','$modelo')"))
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
    }
    ?>
```

en pantalla se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en BD se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el archivo csv se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estructura de la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que se ve en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

consulta en Heidi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Hay algo que **justifique** una manipulación del archivo que podría ser peligrosa, dado que se trata de modificarlo, manipulando su contenido y pudiendo éste ser alterado si contiene errores? Pregunto porque puedes adaptar el código de inserción a MySQL indicando un separador y salto de línea específico. ¿Acaso no es mejor eso que meter mano en los datos?

Comment: si tienes razon y es justo lo uqe hace el codigo he probado y no funciona

Comment: he cambiado el codigo solo me resta finalizar la linea este si funciona pero muestra todo en la primera linea

Comment: Yo me refiero al código SQL que usas para tomar los datos del archivo e insertarlos en la Base de Datos. En esa instrucción podrías especificar otro tipo de separador distingo del estándar, así como otro tipo de salto de línea. No hay necesidad de meterse a modificar el archivo, a no ser que quieras normalizar datos en el mismo que es necesario corregir. No es factible cambiarlo sólamente por el asunto de los separadores o el salto de línea.

Comment: si exacto dejare el archivo como esta tal cual lo que necesito es como lo subo a un mysql cuando viene separado por TAB

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el código SQL que estás usando para subir los datos a la BD y si tienes algún error también agrégalo. Pulsa en [edit]  para actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: ya la he editado al final esta el código he probado con fgetcsv($tabla,1000,";") cambiando el ; por \n por \t y no funciona

Comment: Para indicar que el delimitador es TAB, tienes que usar `\t`, y en cuanto al salto de línea, muchas veces no basta con `\n`, tienes que probar estas cuatro posibilidades: `\r\n` o bien `\n\r` o bien `\n` o bien `\r` OJO, prueba todo esto fuera de la consulta SQL, imprimiendo en pantalla los posibles datos del archivo y cuando funcione entonces le incorporas el código de inserción.

Comment: Notice: fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character in C:\xampp\htdocs  me da este error colocando todas las combinaciones que mencionas

Comment: en la ultima linea me aparece esto: ÿþ"

Comment: Lo que colocaste no es la estructura de la tabla, sino el contenido. Hay que ver cómo está declarado cada campo, el juego de caracteres que usa y, también, saber qué juego de caracteres tiene el archivo CSV para resolver el problema.

Comment: he agregado una imagen de como se ve el CSV

Comment: Lo que necesitamos ver es una imagen de la tabla con su estructura, como [esta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WIoX.png)

Comment: hay esta la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Copia alguna de las consultas para insertar y ejecútala en tu manejador de base de datos, no sé qué estés usando, [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) o algo similar, si hay algún problema, deberías ver un mensaje acerca de texto truncado al insertar.

Comment: ya lo he echo he agregado las pantallas

Comment: Para tratar de reproducir el problema, es necesario **copiar** una de esas consultas con datos reales, no teclear datos inventados.

Comment: A ver, ¿de dónde salen los insert que pones en la captura de pantalla? Si los sacas de la lectura del archivo entonces está leyendo bien, sólo que hay un problema de codificación que debes resolver. Y eso casi nunca se resuelve con el uso de `utf8_decode` y `utf8_encode` , eso ya se viene diciendo por activa y por pasiva aquí en varias preguntas/respuestas. Si hay un problema de codificación hay que encontrar dónde se encuentra ese problema y resolverlo de raíz. Puede ser el archivo, puede ser la conexión a la BD, puede ser el entorno PHP o puede ser la BD misma o la tabla o la columna misma.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías resolverlo en dos pasos.

Lo primero es leer correctamente cada línea del archivo. En mi caso, utilizo la función de php fgets($file,$longituddelinea), que devuelve una línea a la vez.
Puedes ver un ejemplo en el manual de php [funcion.fgets.php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php)

Dentro del while, una vez que tienes la línea, podrías aplicar un modelo de reemplazo simple de:

- " por '' (comillas por ningún caracter)
- --> por ; (tabulado por punto y coma)

lo cual puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$linea = str_replace('\"','',$linea);
$linea = str_replace('\t',';',$linea);
```

Ojalá esta info sea de utilidad.

Comment: lo he hecho y sube en blanco los campos sin data

Comment: ok. La pregunta es si lee bien cada línea? De ser así, sugiero corras solo el primer str_replace, para eliminar las " solamente. Si eso funciona, tal vez debamos utilizar str_regex en lugar del replace.

Comment: he cambiado el codigo solo me resta finalizar la linea este si funciona pero muestra todo en la primera linea

Comment: Es probable que en el reemplazo se haya ido el LF. Sugiero revises ello. A veces, en los editores el LF no alcanza para hacer un salto de linea. Debes incluir un CR + LF por línea. En ASCII esto es \x0d y \x0a o bien \r\n.
De todas formas si quieres volcar esto a una Base de datos, necesitas aislar los campos, no verlos formateados.

Comment: justamente asi es lo necesito para volcar a una BD mysql tengo todo el codigo para volcarlo pero funciona si el limitador es ; ya si cambio por  \r\n da error.

Comment: aqui lo puedes ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426375/cambiar-delimitador-doble-comillas-php

Comment: Ivanm te propongo que cambies el parámetro dentro de preg_match_all. Donde dice '~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~' debes utilizar '(\"\t\")'. Esto reemplazará la secuencia comilla-tab-comilla por ;

Comment: lo hice y no muestra nada en pantalla (Blanco)