# Individualizar datos de un TXT, por línea y por tabulador, en PHP

Tags: php, txt, salto-de-linea, tab

Tengo procesadores de débitos automáticos que funcionan todos de la misma manera, excepto el de un banco.

Cuando recibo un TXT con una línea correspondiente a cada registro, siempre hago:

```
$array_datos = preg_split ( "/\n/", $get_datos );

$tipo_registro [ 0] = "a1CODIGOREGISTRO/a11CODIGOEMPRESA/a10SERVICIO/a22ADHERENTE/a22CBU/a8FECHADEBITO/a11IMPORTE/a15NROFACTURA/a1MONEDA/a2RESULTADO/a8FECHAREVERSO/a17FILLER";

foreach ( $array_datos as $key => $value ) {

$array_registro = unpack ( $tipo_registro [ $value {1}], $value );

if (isset($array_registro['CODIGOREGISTRO'])) { //Compruebo que no sea una línea vacía
    // ACÁ HAGO LOS PROCESOS
}
```

Pero ahora me llega el retorno de un banco que no tiene cantidad de caracteres preestablecidos para cada dato por línea, sino que viene así:

> ```
> 0000018250Juan Perez  00 CARGADO OK   200.00
> 0000018251Angela Lucia  Fernandez 00 CARGADO OK   500.00
> 0000018253Maria Eugenia Gonzalez  00 CARGADO OK   1,000.00
> 0000018254Tonto Francisco Horacio 02 CUENTA CANCELADA 500.00
> ```

Necesito individualizar cada línea, y de cada una, obtener cada campo separado, delimitado por un tabulador.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [cambiar delimitador doble comillas php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426375/cambiar-delimitador-doble-comillas-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con expresiones regulares:

```
$larrLineas = explode("\n",str_replace("\r",'',$get_datos));

$larrRegistros = array();
foreach($larrLineas as $lstrLineas){
    if(preg_match('/^([0-9]+)([\pL\s]+)[\s]*([0-9]+)[\s]*([\pL\s]+)[\s]*([0-9.,]+)$/u',$lstrLineas, $larrMatches)){
        $larrRegistros[] = array(
            'NUMEROCLIENTE'=>$larrMatches[1],
            'NOMBRECLIENTE'=>$larrMatches[2],
            'CODIGOMOVIMIENTO'=>$larrMatches[3],
            'MOVIMIENTO0'=>$larrMatches[4],
            'SALDO'=>$larrMatches[5]
        );
    }
}

print_r($larrRegistros);
```

Empiezo haciendo explode para separar las líneas muy similar a tu preg_split, lo combino con el str_replace para asegurar que los saltos de línea sean tipo UNIX.

Segundo recorro el arreglo y hago uso de la función de preg_match para sacar los valores y los matches los meto a un arreglo asociativo para un posterior manejo fácil.

Explico un poco la expresión regular:

```
/^([0-9]+)([\pL\s]+)[\s]*([0-9]+)[\s]*([\pL\s]+)[\s]*([0-9.,]+)$/u
```

- **/^** Significa que validará desde el inicio de la cadena ingresada.
- **([0-9]+)** Busca que la primer coincidencia sea una cadena de uno o más digitos entre el 0 y el 9. Está hará coincidencia por ejemplo con el número **0000018250**
- **([\pL\s]+)** Busca que la cadena sean una o más letras de cualquier lenguaje y espacios en blanco que pueden ser, tabuladores y espacios, en vez de **\s** podrías escribir **\t\r\n\f**. Está hará coincidencia con el **nombre**.
- **[\s]*** A diferencia de las últimas dos reglas en esta no hay paréntesis, preg_match regresara en la variable $larrMatches las coincidencias registradas en los paréntesis y esta coincidencia no nos importa agarrar, es la parte del espacio antes del código 00 o 02 que muestras, el asterisco significa ninguno o varios y el signo de más significa uno o varios.
- **([0-9]+)** Está busca números y buscará hacer coincidencia con el **código 00 o 02** que muestras.
- **[\s]*** Espacio antes del nombre del movimiento
- **([\pL\s]+)** Busca que la cadena sean una o más letras de cualquier lenguaje y espacios en blanco. Está hará coincidencia con el **movimiento**.
- **[\s]*** Espacio después del nombre del movimiento.
- **([0-9.,]+)** Está busca números, puntos y comas, y buscará hacer coincidencia con el **número con decimales** que muestras.
- **$/u** Significa que validará hasta el fin de la cadena ingresada, ingresando el modificador u que es el encargado de hacer validación de caracteres usando unicode.

Podría hacer que las validaciones sean más rigurosas por ejemplo que sólo haya un punto en el número del saldo, pero no veo la necesidad, ya dependerá de tus necesidades.

Comment: Sos mi heroína! Me has salvado! Tu solución fue perfecta! Muchísimas gracias Tabitha!